# How to make a line as the first line in a TEXT file using Java

Tags: java, text, line

I have a text file "test.txt" with the following content

```
********************
Hi
This is ABC
I learning JAVA and would like to expertize in it.
I joined Stackoverflow today.
********************
```

My requirement is to make the line #4 - I joined Stackoverflow today. as the first line in test.txt so that the file content is as follows:

```
********************
I joined Stackoverflow today.
Hi
This is ABC
I learning JAVA and would like to expertize in it.
I joined Stackoverflow today.
********************
```

Can this be done via code, as I am trying to use various Java Utils, but I am unable to make the line move to the first place.

Comment: Have you tried anything and can you narrow down your question?  You are asking for a lot of code.

Comment: I tried to understand your question... but I got no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: Oh, i got it... but at least have you tried? show your code.

Comment: Please at least show your code attempt when asking such questions. Else 1) how will we know what you might be doing wrong, and 2) you learn to beg but not to code.

Comment: Thanks Tim, mob41 and Hovercraft for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input file being used has duplicates records
DETAILS:
aa
bb
aa
gg
bb
bb

To remove duplicates, I am using the following code

```
File Readfile= new File(n.getProperty("file"));
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Readfile));
Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(10000);
String line;
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
    lines.add(line);
}
reader.close();
File file =new File("stripduplicates.txt");

if(!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getPath()));
   //EDIT done
    writer.write("DETAILS:");
for(String unique: lines){
    //EDIT done
      if(!(unique.startsWith("DETAILS:"))
        {
        writer.write(unique);
        writer.newLine();
        }
}
writer.close();
}
```

The output is coming as needed

DETAILS:
aa
gg
bb

Answer (score 1):

**May not be the best way, but works!**

**First Delete the line**

```
File inputFile = new File("test.txt");
File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

String lineToRemove = "I joined Stackoverflow today.";
String currentLine;

while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
// trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
writer.close(); 
reader.close();
```

**Then Append it at the beginning of your file**

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("yourtextfile.txt"), "rw");
f.seek(0); // to the beginning
f.write(lineToRemove.getBytes());
f.close();
```

Comment: This a possible solution, but I guess the below mentioned skipping of writing that particular line is much easier.
Thanks a ton for your help Johnrao07 :)

Comment: `writer` should be closed before `tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);`